# Laravel: How to count number of membership with respect to status and the package purchased

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

How to count the number of membership with respect to status and the package purchased?

```
|                              Membership Status       |
|    Package Type    | Pending | Active | Cancellation |
| ------------------ | ------- | ------ | ------------ |
| Pearl Premier Full |    5    |   10   |       2      |
| Pearl Premier Odd  |    1    |   7    |       0      |
| Pearl Premier Even |    0    |   3    |       0      |
```

This is my **members** table:

```
| id | status  | package_id |
| -- | ------- | ---------- | 
| 1  | Active  |      3     |
| 2  | Pending |      1     |
```

```
public function package()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Package');
}
```

How to count no. of member with respect to the package purchased also?(package purchased is the travel package, every member will purchased a package)

```
$data = \DB::table('members')->select(\DB::raw(
            'COUNT(CASE status WHEN "Pending" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS pending,
            COUNT(CASE status WHEN "Active" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS active,
            COUNT(CASE status WHEN "Cancellation" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cancelled'
        ))->get();
```

Comment: Your code shows how you count members, i think it is unclear what you mean by "and the package purchased", what logic needs to be done in relation to packages?

Comment: You can use this Eloquent Aggregate Functions: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Comment: package purchased is the travel package, every member will purchased a package

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what you mean by "and the package purchased", but if you want count with if or case condition, you can change `COUNT` to `SUM` and you must grouping your query.

```
$data = \DB::table('members')->select(\DB::raw(
    'SUM(CASE status WHEN "Pending" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending,
    SUM(CASE status WHEN "Active" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active,
    SUM(CASE status WHEN "Cancellation" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled'
))->groupBy(colomn)->get();
```